# How to render a event within time slot in full calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In my project, I want to place an event within time range. For example 09:00 am to 10:00 am. I Googled many times, but not links found.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to place an event within time range."? It's quite unclear what you need...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear if you are asking help to make a full calendar using jQuery.
More information might be better.

Anyway, I think this will help you.
[jQuery Calendar time selection suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527260/jquery-calendar-time-selection-suggestion)

Comment: In my project, full calendar has only 2 views agendaWeek and agendaDay. User can book an appointment by dragging over times. For example 9:00 am to 10:00 am one appointment has been booked. So I will save this information in db. Then by fetching these information from db, I have to create an event in 9:00 am to 10:00 am.

Comment: @JOTHI Are you using a jQuery datepicker and a timepicker or have you built up custom renderers?